# Protractor: How to get text present between two span

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, jasmine

I want to get the text (`SampleList23.csv`) that is present between 2 spans.

#### HTML:

```
<div class="ng-scope" ng-switch-when="false">
    <div class="engage-tag ng-binding">
        <span class="icon-doc-generic-b"/>
        SampleList23.csv                 
        <span class="icon-close close" ng-click="unsetImportFile()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Code I have tried:

```
   1.  expect(element(by.xpath(".//*[@class='engage-tag ng binding']/*")).getAttribute("value")).toContain("SampleList23.csv");
   2.  expect(element(by.xpath("//*[@class='engage-tag ng-binding']/child::node()", 'SampleList23.csv); 
   3.  expect(element(by.xpath("//*[@class='engage-tag ng-binding']/*", 'SampleList23.csv);
```

All above failed to get text.

Comment: It would be good to know the output in case of all the three options that you've tried.

Comment: It looks like you should be able to just get the `text()` in the div . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `span` elements don't have a text, you can basically "ignore" them. In other words, get the parent `div` element and get the text via `getText()`:

```
expect($(".engage-tag").getText()).toEqual("SampleList23.csv");
```

Comment: Will `getText()` fetch you the text here? Doesn't it require resolving a promise? As per [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478905/protractor-element-gettext-returns-an-object-and-not-string) it does.

Comment: @demouser123 in Protractor, `expect()` is internally patched to implicitly resolve promises before executing the assertions. This is quite handy. Thanks.